# how to scrape a description from a website

Tags: web-scraping

I’m looking for scrape some informations from this website: https://www.vogue.it/moda/gallery/met-gala-2021-red-carpet-look-ospiti-celeb

What I’m gonna do is to scrape all the descriptions under the photos, for example “Billie Eilish in Oscar de la Renta custom-made”, “Timothée Chalamet in Haider Ackermann e Converse” and so on. I think the name of the description is “.gallery-slide-caption__dek-container” But it doesn’t scrape anything.
My code is:

```
import pprint
detail_looks = []
for look in list_looks:
    title = ""
    if(len(look.find_elements_by_css_selector(".gallery-slide-caption__dek-container")) > 0):
      title = look.find_elements_by_css_selector("gallery-slide-caption__dek-container")[0].text

    detail_looks.append({'title': title})

len(detail_looks)
pprint.pprint(detail_looks[0:5])
```

But the output is empty: [{'title': ''}, {'title': ''}, {'title': ''}, {'title': ''}, {'title': ''}]

Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: you need to look one level deeper, if I select the item within chrome it's structured like this= div.gallery-slide-caption__dek-container > div.gallery-slide-caption__dek > div > p

So maybe something similar = look.find_elements_by_css_selector("gallery-slide-caption__dek-container gallery-slide-caption__dek")[0].text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all captions you can select all tags with `class="gallery-slide-caption__dek"`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.vogue.it/moda/gallery/met-gala-2021-red-carpet-look-ospiti-celeb"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for i, caption in enumerate(soup.select(".gallery-slide-caption__dek"), 1):
    print(i, caption.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
1 Billie Eilish in Oscar de la Renta custom-made
2 Timothée Chalamet in Haider Ackermann e Converse
3 Amanda Gorman in Vera Wang
4 Keke Palmer
5 Bee Carrozzini in Valentino Haute Couture

...and so on.
```